# The difference between "ma foi" and "eh bien"

Tags: interjections

These two interjections seem to carry the meaning of "well" in English, but I wonder if they have nuances of meaning or such?

> **Ma foi**, je dois dire que j'ai eu mon lot d'aventures pour la journée.
>
> **Eh bien**, je dois dire que j'ai eu mon lot d'aventures pour la journée.

Comment: No difference as far as I know. You can even say:

'Eh bien ma foi, je dois dire que j'ai eu mon lot d'aventures pour la journée.'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No difference in meaning, however I think "ma foi" is less broadly used. I tend to think that it's because literally, it refers to the speaker's religion, which areligious people don't have much use for, and which some religious people find distasteful; but can offer no source to vouch for this other than my own personal experience.

Comment: I think "Ma foi" is only used near Marseille... (and people who moved from there)

Comment: @Random: And Toulouse. Le midi.

Answer (score 0):

[Ma foi](https://www.lawlessfrench.com/expressions/ma-foi/) also seems to be used exclusively by older people, 60+. I've never heard a teen say it, or even anyone middle aged.

Comment: On Marseille/Aix-en-provence, it is very common :)

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't really help but you can also say both at once like:

"Eh bien ma foi, ce fut une bonne journée."

Nevertheless that's more formal speech.